# Substring Function not works on .net cf?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

net CF

I need to use substring to capture the mid of a string.

```
txtpart.Text = "ab12345678cde";
string item = txtpart.Text.Substring(2,8);
```

Which the output should be 12345678.

But it always throws this Exception

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Is there any function other than substring?

Comment: Do you mean `(2,8)`? `"ab12345678cde".Substring(3,8)` is `"2345678c"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Check this Blog from Daniel Moth about substring issue on .net cf

[The Moth Substring Bug on .net cf](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Bug-In-Substring-Under-Netcf.aspx)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your example should return `2345678c` not `12345678` but it doesn't matter.  The code you have is valid and should not throw an error.  Are you passing `ab12345678cde` just for the purpose of example?  Can you show us what is really being passed in when the error occurs?

You can look here to see how your code executes:

http://ideone.com/jufd3

If your length is too long I believe you would get an error, but not the one you saw.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this can help someone...

Here is a simple function that you can use to "get" in the middle of any strings:

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        int Start, End;
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

and to use it, you call:

```
string mySelectedText = getBetween(txtpart.Text, "b", "c");
Debug.WriteLine(mySelectedText);
```

The result would be 12345678

Hope it helps.  Regards